# Symfony using ParamConverter with POST action

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building `rest API`, and have method to save posts.

```
postPostAction(Request $request)
{

}
```

my `POST` request contains all `Entity/Post` properties

How to use `ParamConverter` to have `Entity/Post` in this method parameters like:

```
postPostAction(Post $post)
{

}
```

Do I need create custom `ParamConverter`, or it make sense using ParamConverter only with `PUT` and `GET` ?

Comment: Why not build a Symfony Form Type with an `entity` field?

Comment: @Gerry how to pase form to method params, it's possible ?

Comment: Why do you need them as method parameters? I'd say it is probably technically possible, but surely not appropriate.

Comment: @Gerry you prefer using `Request` in method params ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default paramConverter like this

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @ParamConverter("thePost", class = "AppBundle:Post")
 */
public function postPostAction(Post $thePost)
{
    // ...
}
```

The annotation takes several parameters, there the name of the variable to convert and the class to convert to.

You could even omit the annotation and write

```
public function postPostAction(Post $thePost)
{
    // ...
}
```

this would automatically convert your variable to an entity.

You can find more informations in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html).